# Telerik OpenAccess - Execution of STDistance server side not implemented

Tags: sql-server, telerik-open-access

I have an application which uses Telerik OpenAccess as the ORM and which was working without any problems.

It's now returning the following error when trying to do a query based on STDistance:

> Execution of 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography:STDistance(SqlGeography)' on the database server side currently not implemented.

I'm using OpenAccess 2012.3.1012.  This was working fine and I was of the impression OpenAccess supported Spatial Types since 2011.1 so don't understand why it's now reporting it as unavailable.

I have upgraded the SQL Tools on my machine to SQL 2012 but the database server is running SQL 2008. I found a forum post regarding a similar problem and Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll version 11, but have double checked and I am using version 10.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Problem resolved.  Appears to be a regression in support for SQL Geometry within the product.  

Telerik advise it will be fixed in the next service pack due week commencing 26th Nov.

Comment: Please add this as an answer. Yes, you can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a regression in the SQL Geometry support in the product, that is already fixed. The fix will be part of the next service pack of Telerik OpenAccess ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved. Appears to be a regression in support for SQL Geometry within the product. Telerik advise it will be fixed in the next service pack due week commencing 26th Nov.